# Clojure optional definitions

Tags: clojure

In Python I'm able to do something like:

```
fast_thing_available = True

try:
    import fast_thing
except ImportError:
    fast_thing_available = False

# snip

if fast_thing_available:
   default = fast_thing
else:
   default = slow_thing
```

Is it possible to do the same thing in Clojure?
I've tried next, but it fails (e.g. import is still required):

```
(ns sample.ns)

(def ^:private long-adder-available (atom false))

(try
  (do
    (import 'java.util.concurrent.atomic.LongAdder)
    (swap! long-adder-available (constantly true)))
  (catch ClassNotFoundException e ()))

(when (true? @long-adder-available)
  (do
     ; Here I'm using LongAdder itself
  ))
```

Code throws `IllegalArgumentException: unable to resolve classname: LongAdder` even if `LongAdder` itself is not available.

Comment: So you start a repl, and you type `(import 'java.util.concurrent.NotAClass)` and you get an `IllegalArgumentException` ?  Your code works as expected for me. The `ClassNotFoundException` is caught.

Comment: On another note, your `swap!` form would be better expressed as: `(reset! long-adder-available true)`, and you can also express your `when` more succinctly as: `(when @long-adder-available ...)`, and under both the `try` and the `when`, you do not need a `do`

Comment: @Josh I disagree with your assessment that it works as intended. The important thing is not the ClassNotFoundException raised at runtime by the `import` expression, but the one raised at compile time by the code inside of the `when`, which gets compiled whether or not it will actually be run.

Comment: @amalloy Oops! When I ran the example I completely forgot to actually put the usage of the class in the `when` block. Thanks for the catch! Is your conclusion that what the poster wants to do is not possible?

Comment: Not impossible, but it's gross, hard, and not generally the way things are done in Clojure. You basically have to use reflection instead of referring to the class normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @amalloy in the comments, the code inside `when` does not compile. I am not sure if there is a way to re-write that code so it compiles. However it is possible to avoid compiling it altogether. Clojure macros can be used to exclude code from compilation.

A macro can attempt importing a class and only if that succeeds emit the the code using the class. There are simpler ways to check if a class exists in the classpath, but it is important to call `import` at compile time. That way the code can use simple class names (like `LongAdder`).

When applied to this problem, the solution might look like the sample below. The piece of code calling `import` is a bit ugly with `eval` etc. but it is tough to pass non-literal arguments to `import`. If there is no need for this code to be generic, the class name can be hard-coded and a few other things can be simplified.

```
(ns sample.core)

(defmacro defn-if-class
  "If clazz is successfully imported, emits (defn name args then)
   Emits (defn name args else) otherwise."
  [clazz name args then else]
  (if (try (eval `(import ~clazz)) true (catch Exception e nil))
    `(defn ~name ~args ~then)
    `(defn ~name ~args ~else)))

(defn-if-class java.util.concurrent.atomic.LongAdder
  foo []
  ;; if class exists
  (doto (LongAdder.)
    (. increment)
    (. sum))
  ;; else
  "fallback logic in case the class is not in classpath")

(defn -main [& args]
  (println (foo)))
```

I should mention that the answer is heavily inspired by Jay Fields' blog post "[Clojure: Conditionally Importing](http://blog.jayfields.com/2012/05/clojure-conditionally-importing.html)" and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29451457/1860180).

Comment: I was thinking about a macro, but I thought there is a better way. Thank you.